# Missing base content types in Choose content Type settings wizard

Tags: c#, sharepoint, visual-studio-2015

Im trying to get going with add-ins for sharepoint online and have followed the steps defined in the following walk through.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt148587.aspx

When I get to step 3 however the base content drop down is blank and I can't create the custom content type. 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you confirm that:

- The target SharePoint site is accessible
- That your project is in online mode (as specified in the Server Connection property in the app for SharePoint project property window)
- That your target SharePoint site (as specified in the Site URL property in the app for SharePoint project property window) a Developer site (created with the Developer Site template on SharePoint)

The above troubleshooting steps were taken from:

[Unable to create Content Type within a Sharepoint 2013 App project](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/835000/unable-to-create-content-type-within-a-sharepoint-2013-app-project)